# Advice for Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm new to hyper-v and cloud!

I installed Server 2008 Ent R2 + Hyper-V
Created my VM, and installed my OS on it. (Web server, server 2012 Std, IIS)

So far everything works fine.

But I need to know what are the other ways to do this, the best way and more secure way. for example I noticed that when the host server needs to restart for applying updates obviously the whole server will be restarted and all VMs will be unavailable , how can I sort this out, so the VMs wont be affected.

Thanks

Comment: There's no way for them to *not* be affected. Google is your friend...

Comment: Failover Clustering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. Clustering. First, start by not installing a seriously outdated version of the server (ever heard of Server 2012), then install it as a cluster on multiple machines including a highly available SAN for the storage (starwind has a virtual SAN you can install right on the Windows Server with up to 3 machines mirroring).

Result: When a server resets, the machines can first be moved to another computer and the storage is still online.

Cost? Well, high availability does not come cheap. Wait until you actually have to - you know - administrate them professionally. THAT is when the fun starts.

Answer (score -1):

The way we have dealt with it has been to set up a WSUS server, and schedule all the servers on a particular host (including the host) to update at the same time (ie 5am on Thursdays.)  That way all servers stay up to date and the reboot doesn't affect too much.

The *best* way would be to do the above and have either clustered or backup servers running so that no one server being down for reboots/maintenance will effect core services; but proper HA is a topic for another time and place.

Comment: Actually in a Server 2012 you can set it up to drain the server first - i.e. it restarts once all machines are moved. That requires though that you have their storage on another, high available place.

Comment: We don't have any Hyper-v 3 hosts deployed yet.  But if that's the case then I'll need to set some up in our test environment and re-evaluate our deployment schedule.

Comment: They rock - tons of new features, like no share movement of vm's. You will be surprised.